# Multi-dimensional matrix initialization to ones using opencv gives a linking error

Tags: opencv, multidimensional-array, initialization, unresolved-external

I have a strange error using opencv under visual studio 11. When I do this:

```
int sz[]={3,3,3};
T=Mat(3,sz,CV_32F);
```

or this (2D matrix initialized to ones):

```
T=Mat::ones(3,3,CV_32F);
```

everything works fine

but this (3D matrix initialized to ones):

```
int sz[]={3,3,3};
T=Mat::ones(3,sz,CV_32F);
```

gives me a linking error:

> Error  6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class cv::MatExpr __cdecl cv::Mat::ones(int,int const *,int)"

Why is this? Do I need to link something extra when I initialize n dimensional matrices with ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the ones method create only 2D matrix, if you want to initialize your matrix with a specified values you have to do it with the constructor

```
int sz[]={3,3,3};
T=Mat(3,sz,CV_32F, Scalar::all(1));
```

Comment: I can also infer  this from the error but why the linking error? Is it maybe a method from another class? (I don't think so). I also see no reason why is this only implemented for 2D matrices.

Comment: It seems like the method cv::Mat::ones(int,int const *,int) for multidimensional matrix has been declared in the header files but it has no implementation, from this the linker error